# Android NDK development

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

Im planing on staring to develop games for android but im not sure where i should begin.
I have done a lot of work whit C++ and OpenGL and i would prefer continuing to work in c++ even on android. 
Watching the google i/o 2011 about the NDK and c/c++ programming i got the feeling that it could be done relatively easy.
But i keep reading articles about how difficult it would be and that if i dont have a relay good reason i should stick to the sdk, but im not sure if this is old information and not relevant.

Should i use the ndk just because i like c++ more then java or should i just start whit the sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NDK only provides a subset of what the SDK provides. It's of course more cumbersome and harder to debug. The reason it's there is because you get closer to bare-bones performance and that matters for  games and in particular 3D.

So if you need 100% power or you're porting a game engine written in C++, consider the NDK
If not, stick with the SDK

Comment: I do not know for sure... but Java SDK will prevent you from some troubles with different versions of Android. I think that using Java will be much easier to port your code to different devices/versions. Another thing is that Java on the Android is very well optimized and the performance should not be so low...

Comment: java is the slowest runtime environment as much as i know. but c++ is limited only by the algorithm you use., but remember with great power comes a responsibility.